# Updating Firebird blob with hex binary string through isql utility

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to update Firebird 2.5 database through isql. One of the fields in target database is `BLOB SUB_TYPE -13` (custom blob type). I store gzipped textual data on that field. In my sql script I use hexadecimal notation for binary data, for example

```
x'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'
```

Unfortunately, isql fails with message

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000
filter not found to convert type 1 to type -13
```

I have tried to cast value as

```
cast(x'789CBD5A6D6FE2B816FE7EA5FB1FBCB3D...' as blob sub_type -13)
```

still same error

Comment: Interesting that it converts that binary string literal to a blob sub_type text (sub_type 1) instead of a sub_type binary. I guess you will have to apply `cast(cast(x'...' as blob sub_type binary) as blob sub_type -13)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround to this is to use:

```
cast(x'...' as blob sub_type binary)
```

As I mentioned in the comments, you could also do

```
cast(cast(x'...' as blob sub_type binary) as blob sub_type -13)
```

But as the second cast is not necessary, I would recommend using the shorter form.

The problem is that for some reason the `x'...'` literal is coerced to a `blob sub_type text` instead of the - in my opinion more logical - `blob sub_type binary`. There is an implicit conversion from `sub_type binary` to other user-defined sub-types, but not from `blob sub_type text`), so - without defining a `FILTER` to do the conversion for you - you need to convert to `blob sub_type binary` first.

<sup>Sub-types `binary` and `text` are system-defined aliases for sub-types `0` and `1`. You can also add aliases for user-defined blobs in the table `RDB$TYPES` and use those from your statements instead of the numeric sub-types.</sup>

I reported a ticket in the Firebird tracker: [CORE-6389](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-6389) (which is fixed in Firebird 4).

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, you saved my day (and not the first time :) )